# How can I tell if the text does not fit in a UILabel

Tags: uilabel

I am not looking to resize the label, and I'm not looking to shrink the font size. I just need to know if the current text fits in the current frame of the label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has included this in the UIKit framework. You can calculate the size of a string with a given font using the *sizeWithFont:* method or one of it's variations.

Here's an example:

```
NSString *testStr = @"This is a test string";
CGSize strSize = [testStr sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
CGFloat width = strSize.width;
```

Take the *width* from that example and compare it with the width of your label.

Here are the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

use

[[UILabel text] sizeWithFont:defaultFont constrainedToSize:defaultSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]

method